# How to use FeatureUnion

Tags: feature-extraction

I am trying to solve an exercise problem in my data sceive course. The problem requires me to construct a pipeline and use feature union to extract the most relevant features. Have coded as in the snap below , but keep getting an error message when I try to execute the feature union on my dataset.Need help in resolving this error, please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before I start answering, please note that while posting queries on platforms like StackOverflow, it is essential to paste the code with the question and not to put a screenshot. If you need a working answer, you need to make the task easier for people by giving them access to your code so they can run it.

Now, talking about the error, from what I can observe, you have been using the wrong syntax

```py
FeatureUnion(transformer_list=
                        [('num_pipe', num_pipeline),
                        ('cat_pipe', cat_pipeline)])
```

Above is the correct syntax.
You need to pass a list of tuples, where the tuple's zeroth element is a name and the second element is the actual transformer or the pipeline.

Moreover, FeatureUnion runs two or more transformers in parallel and concat the results side-by-side. So, you also need to make sure that the resulting matrices are of the same dimensions "row-wise".